# Are there any plans for an animated adaptation of the Avatar: The Last Airbender comics?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Are there any plans for animated adaptation of last comics of "Aang the Last Airbender"?

Almost five comics trilogies are released. It seems that is enough material for new season. Any rumors?

Comment: Hey Firanolfind. Sadly, we don't accept speculative answers, so speculations on rumors are out. I can tell you that there's no animated adaption of the comics planned yet, but this question's going to get closed.
(Also, it'd be great, so hopefully they do it some day)

Comment: This is a speculative questions which will invite speculative answers. It is thus off-topic.

Comment: OK, sad. I thought I missed some information about new season. Maybe creators would answer this question :D

Comment: This question doesn't seem speculative to me-- either there are plans for this, or there aren't.  That might change in the future, but it has nothing to do with any of our opinions on the subject.

Comment: __If you think this should be on-topic__, take it [on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9168/70236). Existing consensus reads ["off-topic"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9169/70236).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Very unlikely

During [a 2014 interview](http://www.hypable.com/the-legend-of-korra-creators-confirm-the-end-of-avatar/), co-creators Bryan Konietzko and Mike DiMartino of both *Avatar: The Last Airbender* and *The Legend of Korra* indicated that the comics will be the primary future of the two series, and that they are moving on to other projects:

> “There are more [*Avatar: The Last Airbender*] comics in the works,” Konietzko confirmed. “There may be some other little things, some products here and there, but other than that, nothing major in the works, and there probably won’t be for a long time. We’re moving on to other projects.”

I should point out too that a continuation of the series would likely require network backing. Nickelodeon [gave the last two seasons of Korra poor advertising and slashed their budgets](http://screenrant.com/legend-korra-season-4-episde-8-remembrances-reviews/), and initially only aired the final season on their website instead of TV. It does not appear that Nickelodeon is interested in paying for additional seasons.

There are also logistical issues with bringing back the show. For one, it is very difficult to get all of the voice actors back for a new show, especially one nearly 10 years after the end of it. And not everyone sounds the same. For instance, Aang was voiced by [Zach Tyler Eisen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zach_Tyler_Eisen) when he was aged 9 through 12 during the show's production. Now he is 23 and sounds quite a bit different than he did back then.

Comment: It is so sad!!! I wish Nickelodeon would change their mind. Avatar is amazing phenomenon, imo.

Comment: About voice, Aang grows too, so voice could change as well. I expected that issue, but it seems solvable. Even Iroh - Zuko's uncle voice actor changed because of passing away original actor, and I did't even recognize it.

Comment: @Firanolfind Even if Nickelodeon suddenly decided to write a blank check, the co-creators are moving on. A lot of things have to come together for a show to happen and a lot of people have to be on board. As we're approaching 10 years since the end of Avatar, it's increasingly unlikely that it's going to happen.

Comment: Last comics arriving in a month, this April or May this year. So the project does not look total abandoned.

Comment: @Firanolfind Comments are really only for discussion about the answer (e.g. requesting clarification) and are likely to be deleted. If you'd like to talk about the show casually, there are [a number of chatrooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=scifi.stackexchange.com) for this site where people would be happy to talk about the show.